# Given $f$ is absolutely integrable on $[1, \infty)$, prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_1^\infty f(x^n) dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

We know that $\int_1^\infty |f| dx < \infty $.

I believe we also know that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

I'm unsure how to proceed further but am guessing this involves some application of Dirichlet's Test and integration by parts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}|f(x^{n})|dx=\dfrac{1}{n}\int_{1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{u^{(n-1)/n}}|f(u)|du\leq\dfrac{1}{n}\int_{1}^{\infty}|f(u)|du$.

Comment: How do you know that $\frac{1}{ u^{ \frac{n-1}{n} } } \leq 1$?

Comment: $u\geq 1$, so $u^{(n-1)/n}\geq 1$, flip over then.